# List concatenated keys of a nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

Suppose we have nested dictionary given below. We want, ultimately, to make a list of all of the nested named fields that appear in each dictionary. Concatenate nested field names using a period '.' to defined named fields for nested records. Present the list in alphabetical order. For example, if our data file contained the following
then the ordered list of fields would be:

```
    {
     "name":{"firstName": "ff", "lastName": "ll"},
     "phone": "555",
      "address": {
                  "personal": {"city":"cc", "street": "ss"},
                  "work": "ww"
                  }
     }


["address.personal.city", "address.personal.street", "email", 
 "name.firstName", "name.lastName", "phone"]
```

How to do it? I really want to do such a thing to each dictionary

What I have done so far:

```
let X = {"name":{"first":"FFF","last":"LLL"},
     "address":{"personal":{"city": "cc", "home":"hh"}, "work":"ww"}, 
     "phone":"555"}

def find_deep(dictionary):
    key_list = list(dictionary)
    for key in key_list:
        if type(dictionary[key])==dict:
            key_list[key_list.index(key)] = [key, find_deep(dictionary[key])]
            # key_list[key_list.index(key)] = appen_word_to_list(key, list(dictionary[key]))
    return key_list
```

Above function produces:

```
    y = find_deep(X)
    y = ['phone', ['name', ['last', 'first']], ['address', 
         [['personal', ['city', 'home']], 'work']]]
```

Unrolling this, I have bugs!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classic problem to solve with recursion, with the recursive method adding a level of keys at a time:

```
def find_deep(dictionary, parent):
    ans = []
    for key in list(dictionary):
        # To make sure the first level doesn't get a preceding dot
        initial_dot = "" if parent == "" else "."

        if type(dictionary[key]) == dict:
            # The recursion progresses
            ans.extend(find_deep(dictionary[key], initial_dot.join((parent, key))))
        else:
            # The recursion terminates
            ans.extend([initial_dot.join((parent, key))])
    return ans


x = {"name":{"first":"FFF","last":"LLL"},
     "address":{"personal":{"city": "cc", "home":"hh"}, "work":"ww"}, 
     "phone":"555"}
print(find_deep(x, ""))
```

And the output is, as expected:

`'name.first', 'name.last', 'address.personal.city', 'address.personal.home', 'address.work', 'phone'`

Comment: this is exactly what I needed, you saved my small brain from the pain of attempting this on my own :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion:

```
s = {
 "name":{"firstName": "ff", "lastName": "ll"},
 "phone": "555",
  "address": {
              "personal": {"city":"cc", "street": "ss"},
              "work": "ww"
              }
 }
def trim(f):
   return ['.'.join(i.split('.')[:-1]) for i in f(s)]

@trim
def object_notation(s, last = ''):
   if not isinstance(s, dict):
      yield s
   else:
      for a, b in s.items():
          yield from ['{}.{}'.format(a, i) for i in object_notation(b, a)]
print(object_notation)
```

Output:

```
['name.firstName', 'name.lastName', 'phone', 'address.personal.city', 'address.personal.street', 'address.work']
```